# Grails request getFile method

Tags: grails

Morning. I try to upload a CSV file to fill out my Book domain class. I can google the procedure no problem.  Use request.getFile() and the Grails CSV plugin.

Next, I am trying to look for the document for the request.getFile() method. I want to know what it is doing.  So, I google getFile(). It brings me to the Grails document page.  The page does not have any information regarding the getFile() method.  It says request is a HttpServletRequest.  I click the link. it takes me to the Oracle Java API page.  There does not have any information for the getFile() method either.  So, I continue.  It says HttpServletRequest is a ServletRequest. The ServletReqest page is not any information for the getFile() method either.  There is no more link to click.

So, what/where is getFile() coming from?  What other keywords can I search to find the document?

Thanks!  Happy Tuesday.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, what/where is getFile() coming from?

The method is defined in `MultipartRequest`.

One of the places that the `getFile` method is documented is at https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartRequest.html#getFile-java.lang.String-.

> What other keywords can I search to find the document?

Which keywords did you use?

Comment: Thanks!  I also figured it out.  But I was doing the research the hard way. I put **int x = request.getFile('xxx')** to bait Grails to get me the error showing that getFile is a spring.io class.  I tried "grails getFile", "request getFile", "groovy getFile", "servletrequest getFile".  None of these points me to the spring.io link you post.  How do you know getFile is from spring.io?  My wording is not that good.  I don't mean "how" in a sense that how it work.  Let me try again.  What kind of research have you done to point you to the spring.io page?  thanks again.

Comment: `"What kind of research have you done to point you to the spring.io page?"` - I have been using Grails since before we released the first version of Grails (and before the spring.io site existed) so I am familiar with the surrounding apis. There are a lot of ways to figure it out.  You could step debug into it, for example.